# Why return statement works for void as return type in C?

Tags: c, function, return, void, c89

NOTE: I am using windows 7 and  gcc compiler on code blocks IDE.

I have found out that all forms of return
statements can be used if the return type
of function is void

for example:

```
void message() //If i skip this declaration still it works
main()
{
    message();
}
void message()
{
    return 5; //also return 5.0 and return a(some variable) also works
}
```

Since, `void` refers to 'nothing is returned' then how can we use return statements here. Does it mean that all programs return something whether it is void or other return type?

One more query I have regarding `void` as return type:

If I use this program

```
main()
{
    printf("%d",message());
}

void message()
{
}
```

It gives output as 1,

and doesn't give error

But I get an error if I use this:

```
void message(); //when I use the declaration

main()
{
    printf("%d",message());
}

void message()
{

}
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: How do you compile your code, did your compiler emmits some warnings?

Comment: [this](http://www.slideshare.net/GiorgiMoniava/introduction-to-undefined-behavior-in-c-and-c?qid=bafa48f8-4f11-4053-91d1-403910234b5c&v=&b=&from_search=1) should be useful, although it might not directly answer your first question. The earlier you get familiar with notion of UB, better for you, IMO.

Comment: Your code has **undefined behaviour**. This is exactly how undefined the undefined behaviour can be.

Answer (score 5):

I am not very sure about C89, but in C11, I can see in chapter §6.8.6.4

> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is `void`. [...]

So, your code violates the standard.

Regarding the second part,

- while missing declaration, due to the now-obsolete *type-defaults-to-`int`* property, it *appeared* to work, but it actually invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because, you're supplying a `void` type as `int` argument.
- While having a forward declaration (with return type as `void`), due to mismatch of return type, error is prominent.

Comment: The same sentence appears in the C99 standard.

Answer (score 3):

The C11 standard draft n1570 says the following in the foreword:

> Major changes in the second edition [that is, C99] included:
>
> [...]
>
> — return without  expression  not  permitted  in  function  that  returns  a  value  (and  vice versa)

---

C89 standard then says the following:

> Constraints
>
> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

However, nothing is mentioned about prohibiting a return statement without an expression appearing in a function whose return type is *not* `void`.

Thus returning a value from `void` is not correct in C89 either.

---

Note that `main()` without return type is not allowed by C11 either. However, GCC is quite relaxed about many of these border cases, unless `-pedantic-errors` option is provided.